# Do Catholics regard the wine at The Wedding at Cana as "holy" wine or "normal" wine?

Tags: catholicism, gospel-of-john

> Jesus said to the servants, “Fill the jars with water”; so they filled them to the brim. Then he told them, “Now draw some out and take it to the master of the banquet.” They did so, and the master of the banquet tasted the water that had been turned into wine. [John 2:7-9](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+2%3A7-9&version=NIV)

My Question: Do Catholics regard the wine at The Wedding at Cana as "holy" wine or "normal" wine?

Emphasis: Do they have a special reverence for this wine, similar to how they have a reverence for relics?

Comment: Normal but exceptionally good wine. The entire event is the one with much greater significance cf. [this answer of mine](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/why-do-catholics-put-so-much-faith-in-the-virgin-mary/30943#30943).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wine was just wine, but it was very good wine.

> the steward called the bridegroom 10 and said to him, “Everyone serves
>   the good wine first, and then the inferior wine after the guests have
>   become drunk. But you have kept the good wine until now.” [John 2:9-10](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+2%3A9-10&version=NRSVCE)

The wine no longer exists so it is not a relic. The wine was not sacramental, so it was not holy in that sense. There is no teaching that I know of that says the wine was blessed. The fact that it was consumed as any other wine would be suggests there was nothing special about the wine other than it being created miraculously and being good in the sense of being a good wine.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but I'd add that, *if* we had any of this wine, it would be regarded as an important relic.